# Mean excluding zero and na for all columns with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want do do a mean of my dataframe with the dplyr package for all my colums.

```
n = c(NA, 3, 5) 
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
b = c(3, 0, 5) 
df = data.frame(n, s, b)
```

Here I want my function to get mean = 4 the n and b columns
I tried `mean(df$n[df$n>0])` buts it's not easy for a large dataframe.
I want something like `df %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))` ...
Thanks

Comment: Just use `my_mean <- function(x) mean(x[x != 0],na.rm = TRUE)`? What you want to happen to the `s` column?

Comment: Could do `df %>% summarise_each(funs(mean(.[!is.na(.) & . != 0])), -s)` probably. Or `df %>% summarise_each(funs(mean(.[. != 0], na.rm = TRUE)), -s)` similar to jorans suggestion.

Comment: Thanks David perfect !! what's mean "-s" ?

Comment: It means not to include the `s` column into commutation as it is non-numerical

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want 0s it's probably that you consider them as NAs, so let's be explicit about it, then summarize numeric columns with `na.rm = TRUE` :

```
library(dplyr)
df[df==0] <- NA
summarize_if(df, is.numeric, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
#   n b
# 1 4 4
```

As a one liner:

```
summarize_if(`[<-`(df, df==0, value= NA), is.numeric, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

and in base `R` (result as a named numeric vector)

```
sapply(`[<-`(df, df==0, value= NA)[sapply(df, is.numeric)], mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Cf elegant David Answer :

```
df %>% summarise_each(funs(mean(.[!is.na(.) & . != 0])), -s)
```

Or

```
df %>% summarise_each(funs(mean(.[. != 0], na.rm = TRUE)), -s)
```